# Discord bot log the users server join-left with

Tags: javascript, discord

My code :

```
  //Welcome & goodbye messages\\
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  member.roles.add(member.guild.roles.cache.find(i => i.name === 'Among The Server'))

  const welcomeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

  welcomeEmbed.setColor('#5cf000')
  welcomeEmbed.setTitle('**' + member.user.username + '** is now Among Us other **' + member.guild.memberCount + '** people')
  welcomeEmbed.setImage('https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/93GAa4wm3z4HbenzLbxWeQ-650-80.jpg.webp')

  send.message.channel("767685428018413571").send(welcomeEmbed)
})

client.on('guildMemberRemove', member => {
  const goodbyeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

  goodbyeEmbed.setColor('#f00000')
  goodbyeEmbed.setTitle('**' + member.user.username + '** was not the impostor there are **' + member.guild.memberCount + '** left Among Us')
  goodbyeEmbed.setImage('https://gamewith-en.akamaized.net/article/thumbnail/rectangle/22183.png')

  send.message.channel("767685428018413571").send(goodbyeEmbed)
})
//Welcome & goodbye messages end\\
```

I'm join the test server with my test account. And bot don't send a message about , you are join the server etc.

Please help me.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this lines `send.message.channel`. Send is not defined, you need define the channel first and send the embebed message after.

```
const channel = client.channels.cache.get("767685428018413571");
channel.send(welcomeEmbed);
```

I hope you find it useful

**EDIT**

If you prefere use the name channel

```
const channelName = 'Name of the channel'
const channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === channelName)
channel.send(welcomeEmbed);
```

Normally I use .env to access enviroments variables like Channel Name

```
const channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === process.env.CHANNEL_NAME)
channel.send(welcomeEmbed);
```

Comment: And I am try this : 

```
  client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    member.guild.channels.get('767685428018413571').send("Welcome"); 
});
```

But again failed, no send a response

Comment: This is edited code : 
https://hizliresim.com/2NVzWJ

Comment: And with the Channel name? `const channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === channelName)` where `channelName = 'Name of the channel'`